# How to initial window.__INITIAL_STATE__ to data in a .ejs view file?

Tags: reactjs, server, client, ejs, server-side-rendering

I am trying to pass data to client-side by initializing window.**INITIAL_STATE**, however, this keeps giving me the "Expression expected" error which I am not sure how to fix

```
    <script>
       window.__INITIAL_STATE__ = <%- JSON.stringify(initialState) %>;
    </script>
```

Comment: Can you try putting the ejs expression in quotes like `window.__INITIAL_STATE__ = '<%- JSON.stringify(initialState) %>';`

Comment: yeah this worked

Comment: Hi Laily, I have added the same as the answer. Please mark as accepted answer if you found it useful. :)

Answer (score 0):

You need to wrap the expression in quotes as follows,

```js
<script>
  window.__INITIAL_STATE__ = '<%- JSON.stringify(initialState) %>';
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend you to change the approach and put `JSON.stringify` into

```
<script id="__INITIAL_STATE__" type="application/json"> 
    {JSON.stringify(data).replace(/</g,'\\u003c')}
</script>
```

and on the client side just do

```
const state = JSON.parse(document.getElementById('__INITIAL_STATE__').textContent)
```

according to chrome devs it is faster solution and you dont get any surprises related to quotes.

Faster apps with JSON.parse (Chrome Dev Summit 2019): https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ff4fgQxPaO0